# Getting mschart series source data

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I have an mschart with source data `List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>`.
I set datasource by data binding:

```
chartMain.Series[id].Points.DataBind(sourceData, "Item1", "Item2", string.Empty);
```

How can I retrieve source data in its original format (`List<Tuple<DateTime,double>>`)?
Sg. like this:

```
List<Tuple<DateTime,double>> sourceData = chartMain.Series[id].SomeGetSourceDataMethod;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no built-in solution, I set original datasource as 'Tag' property of series, from where I can retrieve anytime I want.

Answer (score 0):

Prevention is better than cure, why would you ever want to get the data source from the chart ? seems a lopsided approach. Could you not just cache your 'sourceData' and use it from cache when subsequently required rather than trying to retrieve it from the chart control ?

Or is there a reason behind why you specifically need to retieve the bound data from the chart ?

Comment: Because I don't want to store source data in a seperate class scope variable just for this. I thought it was a very basic feature of a chart control to get source data back. I need that in chart events, like mouse move, to get closest data point to mouse cursor. Cause it is another basic feature, that is not built in ms chart control, so I have to mine it from original source data.

Comment: what object is being returned from this: chartMain.DataSource ?

Comment: An object. But I don't need chart datasource, I need series datasource, cause I can have more series.

Comment: Try casting that object to List<Tuple<DateTime,double>> as this may be what you have bound to the series. I havent tried this in code as yest just a suggestion.

Comment: It is not a godd solution, cause every series have its own datasource, so I can have even 20 series with 20 datasources.

Comment: I can store original datasources by every series's tag property and retrieve it, but I thought there is a more straightforward built in way.